# Хранение месяца и дня в бд

Tags: mysql, дата

Нужно хранить в базе данных месяц и день праздников, год не нужен. Как это реализовать?

---

**добавка из комментария:**

Допустим, я храню месяц и день, когда начинается праздник, и месяц и день, когда заканчивается. Как я потом смогу вычислить продолжительность праздника в днях? С помощью strtotime, как я понимаю, это не получится сделать.

Comment: Да как угодно, числом "MMDD" например, строкой "DD.MM" или еще какой, двумя полями, в виде поля даты с фиксированным годом. как удобнее так и храните

Answer (score 3, accepted):

например, так:

```
alter table ... add column (day int, month int);
```

---

**ответ на вопрос в комментарии:**

продолжительность праздника в случае хранения дня и месяца его начала и конца можно посчитать, например, так:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78d9b/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (day1 int, month1 int, day2 int, month2 int);

insert into t values
   (1, 1, 3, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select datediff(
  date(
    concat(year(now()),"/",month2,"/",day2)
  ),
  date(
    concat(year(now()),"/",month1,"/",day1)
  )
) + 1 as days from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78d9b/3/0)**:

```
| days |
|------|
|    3 |
```

Comment: Хорошо допустим я храню месяц и день когда начинается праздник и месяц и день когда заканчивается,как я потом смогу вычислить продолжительность праздника  в днях. С помощью strtotime как я понимаю это не получится сделать.

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что не получится?

Comment: @quaresma89, я обновил ответ.